# What is burst length with respect to the AXI specification?

Tags: arm, soc

I am reading AXI specification, and I am encountering "burst length". Please enlighten me what is it.

Answer (score 5):

If you are reading the spec you will see it says that burst length is the number of data transfers per burst, which they call beats.  Each beat can be a number of bytes specified by burst size.

So for example if you wanted to transfer 8 bytes starting at address zero you could use a burst size of 1 byte, and a burst length of 8.   Then you would get 8 sequential transfers of 1 byte for a total of 8bytes.  It's up to the slave to increment the address to the next byte location and put it out on the bus.

Answer (score 1):

Burst length is number of data transfers for the burst like if ur burst length is 4 then the burst is 4 number of sequential data. now the burst size is like width of that each data, As per the AXI4 spec the burst size should be min of 8bits (1byte) that can be called as beat. if not it comes under error strobe that is invalid strobe.